# vss sample hardware provider

Tags: c++, dll, com, shapefile

I've been trying to follow the instructions to install the sample `VSS` hardware provider that comes with the Windows `SDK`. I have been able to compile the code successfully with `VS2013` for 64bit platform. However when I try to install the provider i get the following error..

Unregistering the existing application.

> - Create the catalog object
> - Get the Applications collection
> - Populate...
> - Search for VssSampleProvider application.
> - Saving changes.

Done.

Creating a new COM+ application

> - Creating the catalog object
> - Get the Applications collection
> - Populate.
> - Add new application object
> - Set app name = VssSampleProvider>
> - Set app description = VSS HW Sample Provider
> - Set app access check = true- Set encrypted COM communication = true
> - Set secure references = true
> - Set impersonation = false
> - Save changes.
> - Create Windows service running as Local System
> - Add the DLL component

ERROR:

> - Error code: -2146368511 [0x80110401]
> - Exit code: 113
> - Description:
> - Source:
> - Help file:
> - Help context: 0

COM+ Errors detected: (1)

> (COM+ ERROR 0) on c:\vsssampleprovider\VssSampleProvider.dll
>          ErrorCode: -2146368475 [0x80110425]
>          MajorRef: c:\vsssampleprovider\VssSampleProvider.dll

Looking up for `COM error code -2146368475 [0x80110425]` I could only find that `DLL` load failed.

Even Viewer logs show a warning saying ...
Unable to load `DLL` `c:\vsssampleprovider\VssSampleProvider.dll`

> Process Name: dllhost.exe Comsvcs.dll file version: ENU
>   2001.12.10530.16384

`shp` during component registration. Unable to validate `DLL` entry points.

### #

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to get it working.

1. Using dependency walker identified that MSVCP120.dll and MSVCR120.dll were not being found.
2. Copied these dlls from C:\Windows\System32 to the same folder where the VSSSampleProvider.dll was present.